# Show that $\exists \xi \in [0,2] : \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx=2f(\xi)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is stated as following:

> Show that $\exists \xi \in [0,2] : \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx=2f(\xi)$ where $f(x)$ is continous in $[0,2]$

**Solution:**

Using the fact that $f(x)$ is continous on a closed and bounded interval, it attains both a minimum and a maximum on that interval:

$m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for some $m \leq M$ where $m,M \in \mathbb{R}$

This implies that :

$m\int_{0}^{2}xdx \leq \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx \leq M\int_{0}^{2}xdx$

Both the LHS and RHS integrals calculates to 2, hence we get:

$m \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx \leq M$

Using the intermediate value property, $f(x)$ attains every value in between $m$ and $M$, hence $\exists \xi \in [0,2] : \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx = f(\xi)$ which is equivalent to $ \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx = 2f(\xi)$

$\square$

---

I hope my solution is correct. However, I still have some questions regarding it. There're some places in my solution where I doubt whether the "move" is right or not.

One of which is the following:

- Using the intermediate value property, $f(x)$ attains every value in between $m$ and $M$, hence
  $\exists \xi \in [0,2] : \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx = f(\xi)$

Is it possible to apply the intermediate value property at this instance? I'm thinking that since we have the expression $xf(x)$ as our integrand, this would only be reasonable to argue for if I said that $xf(x)$ attains every value in between $m$ and $M$. In other terms, why, if it works of course, can the intermediate value property be applied here?

Thanks!

Comment: Other than the fact that you never mentioned $f$ was continuous on $[0,2]$ when you stated the problem, the proof looks good. You applied the intermediate value theorem correctly.

Comment: @DionelJaime Thank you, I'll make sure to edit that to the question.

Comment: Note that you can simply apply the [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) in the form $\int _{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx=f(c)\int _{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the link